# Partial sum of exponential with $i$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $y\in\{0,1,2,\cdots,n-1\}$ then what is the partial sum:

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{2\pi iky/n}$$

I think that

$$ e^{2\pi iky/n} = (-1)^{\frac{2ky}{n}} = 1$$

so $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{2\pi iky/n} = n$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing $r=e^{2\pi iy/n}$ and assuming that $r\ne1$ (it depends on $y$ and $n$), we get
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}r^k=\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}=\frac{1-e^{2\pi iy}}{1-e^{2\pi iy/n}}.
$$
Otherwise, if $r=1$, then indeed $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}r^k=n$.

Comment: @hypergeometric Precisely why I don't use the formula in that case, right? Did you get it?